# Finiteness of groups of automorphisms preserving ample divisors.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $H$ be an ample divisor class of an abelian variety $X$ over the complex numbers. Is the group of autormorphisms of $X$ that preserve $H$ finite?
I guess that the answer is yes but I cannot show it.
Is there a simple reason for this or can one give a reference for it?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3716/what-are-the-automorphism-groups-of-principally-polarized-abelian-varieties) on MO.